# Does psycopg2.connect inherit the proxy set in this context manager?

Tags: python, django, proxy, psycopg2

I have a Django app below that uses a proxy to connect to an external Postgres database. I had to replace another package with psycopg2 and it works fine locally, but doesn't work when I move onto our production server which is a Heroku app using QuotaguardStatic for proxy purposes. I'm not sure what's wrong here

For some reason, the `psycopg2.connect` part returns an error with a different IP address. Is it not inheriting the proxy set in the context manager? What would be

```
from apps.proxy.socks import Socks5Proxy
import requests

PROXY_URL = os.environ['QUOTAGUARDSTATIC_URL']


with Socks5Proxy(url=PROXY_URL) as p:
    public_ip = requests.get("http://wtfismyip.com/text").text
    print(public_ip) # prints the expected IP address
    print('end')
        try:
            connection = psycopg2.connect(user=EXTERNAL_DB_USERNAME,
                                              password=EXTERNAL_DB_PASSWORD,
                                              host=EXTERNAL_DB_HOSTNAME,
                                              port=EXTERNAL_DB_PORT,
                                              database=EXTERNAL_DB_DATABASE,
                                              cursor_factory=RealDictCursor  # To access query results like a dictionary
                                              )  # , ssl_context=True
        except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
                logger.error('Unable to connect to Illuminate database')
                raise e
```

Error is:

```
    psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "12.345.678.910", user "username", database "databasename", SSL on
```

Basically, the IP address `12.345.678.910` does not match what was printed at the beginning of the context manager where the proxy is set. Do I need to set a proxy another method so that the psycopg2 connection uses it?